# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: nodejs, npm

My environment is a little different.
I updated from 14.04 to 16.04 to 18.04.

My desktop PC 18.04 has npm installed.

```
$ npm -version
3.5.2

# nodejs -v
v8.10.0

# apt install npm 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ubuntu Server 18.04 Node.js and npm install

```
sudo apt remove --purge nodejs npm
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt autoremove
```

Find the latest version at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall
Latest version 10.x now

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn

npm -version
6.1.0
nodejs -v
v10.7.0
```

Comment: You saved me man I was loosing hope and finally you came as a beam of light in my dark life.

Comment: The part of `sudo apt-key add-` should be `sudo apt-key add -` with a little space after `add` word.

Comment: For me this installs nodejs, but npm is still missing.

Comment: npm is still missing here.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time. I'm so happy it was the first solution I found to the obstacle of installing npm.

Comment: npm should be packaged with nodejs. I don't remember when they started packaging them together but it was well before node v10 was released. If you follow the directions above and npm isn't installed you have something else is wrong with your host environment .